# Where is the git documentation that specifies that a reset can take a branch name as an argument?

Tags: git, git-reset, code-documentation

I've scanned the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) and I see no mention of how to reset to a branch's latest commit. I only see `[<commit>]` used but sure enough, you can specifiy 'origin/develop' in `git reset --hard origin/develop` and it works.

Am I missing something in the docs, or is there something implicit in git that I am not groking?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefcommit-ishacommit-ishalsocommittish "*commit-ish (also committish)

    A commit object or an object that can be recursively **dereferenced to a commit object**.*" A commit ID (SHA-1), a branch, a tag, `HEAD`.

Comment: Ah, insightful. But why not specify [<commit-ish>] in the docs?

Comment: You can try to report that as a minor documentation bug or even submit a patch. See https://github.com/git/git#readme "*The user discussion and development of Git take place on the Git mailing list -- everyone is welcome to post bug reports, feature requests, comments and patches to git@vger.kernel.org (read Documentation/SubmittingPatches for instructions on patch submission and Documentation/CodingGuidelines).*".

Comment: “commit-ish/committish” is documented in `man gitglossary`.